# Perl compare version numbers 5.1 < 5.10

Tags: perl, version

I am having difficulties in comparing 2 versions. If we have 5.1 and 5.10 then 5.1 should be smaller than 5.10. I know that in decimal it should read 5.01 and 5.10. But is there a way to compare it using 5.1 and 5.10?

```
perl -e 'use warnings; use version; if (version->parse("5.1") < version->parse("5.10")) { print "ok"; }'
```

Comment: Please do not use echo and backticks to print Perl one-liners. Perl can print just fine by itself.

Comment: sure. I changed it. but that does not change anything on the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`version`](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) module documentation shows how to do this:

```
print version->declare('5.1')->numify;  # 5.00100
print version->declare('5.10')->numify; # 5.01000
```

Comment: You don't need to numify; you can use `<` and such on the returned objects.

Comment: @ikegami : Right you are

Answer (score 4):

Use the code module [CPAN::Version](http://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN/Version.html) :

```
use CPAN::Version;
say CPAN::Version->vlt("5.1","5.10") ? "OK" : "KO";
```

**output:**

```
OK
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Perl has two comparison operators, for numbers and strings. None of them works the way you want. If you just want to avoid using `version`, you can for example use `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @v = qw(5.1 5.10);

sub by_version {
    my @a = split /\./, $a;
    my @b = split /\./, $b;
    $a[0] <=> $b[0] or $a[1] <=> $b[1];
}

say for sort by_version @v;
```