# Cannot compare two version string by calling perl oneliner from bash

Tags: bash, perl, comparison, version

I want a bash function to return 0 if the result of one comparison between to version numbers is true and to return 1 if it's false so here's what I do :

```
$ perl -e "exit(!(0.9.8.8 < 0.9.10.0))"
$ echo $?
1
```

But it does not work because if I change the comparison sign, the exit code is  the same :

```
$ perl -e "exit(!(0.9.8.8 > 0.9.10.0))"
$ echo $?
1
```

This simple code works with floats but not with version numbers, how can I make my code to work for version numbers ?

Comment: Try this: `perl -Mversion -e 'exit(!(version->parse("0.9.8.8")<0.9.10.0))'`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Is this normal that you use the `parse()` method only for the first version number ?

Comment: @SebMa After reading the documentation, I think it is safer to parse both versions. I will write an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19973852/1030675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl literals like `0.1.2.3` are interpreted as [`vstrings`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.26.1/perldata.html#Version-Strings) and have magic associated with them:

> A literal of the form `v1.20.300.4000` is parsed as a string composed of
>   characters with the specified ordinals. This form, known as v-strings,
>   provides an alternative, more readable way to construct strings,
>   rather than use the somewhat less readable interpolation form
>   `"\x{1}\x{14}\x{12c}\x{fa0}"`. This is useful for representing Unicode
>   strings, and for comparing version "numbers" using the string
>   comparison operators, `cmp`, `gt`, `lt` etc. If there are two or more dots
>   in the literal, the leading `v` may be omitted.

So when you compare `0.9.8.8 < 0.9.10.0` you are comparing to `vstrings` numerical less than, this would lead to a warning like (if you enable `warnings`):

```
Argument "\0^I\n\0" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at -e line 1.
```

You should use string comparison for `vstrings`, 
see [this blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/04/a-guide-to-versions-in-perl.html) for more information.

However, it is better to use the [version](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) module to compare versions.

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/version):

> If you need to compare version numbers, but can't be sure whether they
>   are expressed as numbers, strings, v-strings or version objects, then
>   you should use version.pm to parse them all into objects for
>   comparison.
>   [...]
>   Version objects overload the cmp and <=> operators. Perl automatically
>   generates all of the other comparison operators based on those two so
>   all the normal logical comparisons will work.
>   This may give surprising results:
>
> ```
> $v1 = version->parse("v0.97.0");
> $bool = $v1 > 0.96; # FALSE since 0.96 is v0.960.0
> ```
>
> Always comparing to a version object will help avoid surprises.

So you can do:

```
perl -Mversion -e 'exit !(version->parse("0.9.8.8")<version->parse("0.9.10.0"))'
```

Comment: Should be equivalent to `exit (version->parse("0.9.8.8") >= version->parse("0.9.10.0"))`.

Comment: Or just `perl -Mversion -e'exit version->parse("0.9.8.8") >= "0.9.10.0"'`

Comment: And of course, the OP probably wants at least of the versions to be variable, so `perl -Mversion -e'exit version->parse($ARGV[0]) >= "0.9.10.0"' -- "$v"`